# Abstract Class Help in C++

Tags: c++, class, virtual, abstract

For an assignment I am trying to emulate this class structure (and learn how to use virtual/abstract classes. I have all of the pieces in place but am encountering an issue.
[image]

I want each boat to at least have a hull inside of it. These hull objects would not be Hulls, but rather children of Hull (MonoHull, MultiHull). The problem is I can't figure out how to add a type 'Hull' to the boat class because VS tells me you cant make an object from an abstract class. How should I go about this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Add a `Hull*` to the boat class.

Comment: That's it! Thanks!

Comment: What's in your `Water` class? Does it inherit from `Hydrogen` and `Oxygen`? Is `Atom` an pure virtual class with `electron`, `protons` and `neutrons` as virtual members?

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting this right, `MonoHull` and `MultiHull` are specializations of the `Hull` class.

What you can do in this case is derive `MonoHull` and `MultiHull` from the `Hull` class, and then include a `Hull*` member in your `Boat` class, which can point to a `MonoHull` or `MultiHull` object.

Same with the `Propulsion` class and its `Paddle` and `Sail` derivatives.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Hull*` pointer to the `Boat` class, which points to an object instance of any of the `Hull` subclasses.  With the use of `virtual` functions in the base class, you can invoke overridden versions of the functions at runtime.

Comment: I would tend to recommend using a `std::unique_ptr<Hull>` member instead.